# display loop only if a post meta data exist

Tags: custom-field

I'm looking to display the following loop, only if a custom field data exists, if not, I don't want to display anything.

```
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );?>
  <!-- info --> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any guessing?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid preprocessing the data, this will work (though it's definitely the quick and dirty method):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true ); ?>
    <?php if( $data != '' ) : ?>
        <!-- info --> 
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Otherwise (and this is definitely the better way to go if you need the best functionality), you can do a preliminary loop through the data (or even get different data using the meta), determine if any of the posts have meta, then conditionally execute the loop.

Comment: That will interfere in the post count, and can also make navigation and other stuff look weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `query_posts` behavior without even changing a template file.

```
function custom_query($request) {
    $params = array(
        'meta_key' => 'custom_field_name',
        'meta_value' => 'custom_field_value'
    );
    return array_merge($request, $params);
}
add_filter('request', 'custom_query');
```

Comment: You solution does not take into account whether or not it is the primary query, but I agree that preprocessing, not conditionals, are the way to go. I've edited my answer to reflect as such.